# Batch modify nodes in cypher query based on a regex

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I have a property on several thousand nodes in my database, that captures the path of a file, eg: `dirA/dirB/dirC/file`. However, I have incorrectly set some of them to be 
`dirA/dirB/dirC/file/file`.

On the other hand, there are other files that have their paths correctly entered. 
eg: `dirA/dirX/file`.

I am trying to update all the nodes with faulty paths and not touch the nodes that have a correct path on their property.

1. Any tips on the right regex to use in this case?
2. How do I batch process these in cypher?

I expect that I should use some query of the form:
`match(x) where x.Path contains()`

```
MERGE (n:Node {Path: < some regex here >})
SET n.Path = REPLACE(n.Path < remove the last part of the path >, < some regex>)
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE n.Path =~ '.*(/[^/]*)\\1'
SET n.Path = apoc.text.replace(n.Path, '/[^/]*$', '')
RETURN n
```

You definitely do not want to use `MERGE`, since you are not trying to create new nodes. The `WHERE` clause finds paths that end with the same path element twice (note: the `=~` operator always matches the *entire* value), and the APOC function [apoc.text.replace](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_overview_text_functions) does the replacement.